# pg_dump with -j option and -Z

Tags: postgresql, database-backups, pg-dump, postgresql-12

I am about to backup 120 Gb database. I kept on failing when using PGADMIN backup (because of VPN disconnection after 7 hours running) or SQLMaestro (out of memory issue after 3 hours running).

So I want to run it on the server using `pg_dump`. The command I want to use is : `time pg_dump -j 5 -Fc -Z 1 db_profile_20210714 -f /var/lib/postgresql/backup2/` (I want to measure the time as well, so I put `time`). And after that I will run `pg_dumpall -g`

I have 30 cores server and backup drive mounted on NFS. Postgres 12 running on Ubuntu 12.

Questions :

1. If I use -Z 0, will it undo the default compression of -Fc ? (-Fc is compressed by default)
2. Does the usage of `-j 5` and `-Z 1` counter productive to each other ? I read from article that to throttle pg_dump process so that it wont cause I/O spike, one can use -Z between 3 and 5. But what if some one want to utilize the cores and compress at once, is it effective / efficient ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you use `-Z 0`, the custom format dump will be uncompressed. `-j` and `-Z` are independent from each other, and you cannot use `-j` with the custom format. If using compression speeds up the dump or not depends on your bottleneck. If that is the network, compression can help. Otherwise, compression usually makes `pg_dump` slower.

Comment: If I cant use `-j` with custom format `Fc`, I have to use it with `Fd`. So it will be like `time pg_dump -j 5 -Fd -Z 1 db_profile_20210714 -f /var/lib/postgresql/backup2/` . By "Effectiveness" I mean combining `Z` and `-j` will not make things any faster compared to just using `-j`